# Array : Replace part of array object with other array object

Tags: arrays, typescript, replace

I have an array :

```
{
    "count": 8,
    "id": "accountId",
    "name": " Account Id",
    "values": [
        {
            "count": 2,
            "id": "1234456789000",
            "name": "1234456789000"
        },
        {
            "count": 1,
            "id": "135792468045",
            "name": "135792468045"
        },
        {
            "count": 1,
            "id": "309983110022",
            "name": "309983110022"
        },
        {
            "count": 2,
            "id": "432112426686",
            "name": "432112426686"
        },
        {
            "count": 1,
            "id": "6ee26149-a156-4665-bd26-a6e46b49a70f",
            "name": "6ee26149-a156-4665-bd26-a6e46b49a70f"
        },
        {
            "count": 1,
            "id": "927b48ce-efe4-4c20-98f0-ec6c54f59b45",
            "name": "927b48ce-efe4-4c20-98f0-ec6c54f59b45"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I have a 2nd array :

```
[
    {
        "count": 2,
        "id": "432112426686",
        "name": "432112426686"
    },
    {
         "count": 2,
         "id": "1234456789000",
         "name": "1234456789000"
    }
]
```

The second array, I have filtered based on some requirement.
I want to replace the values from 1st array with second array.

Using typescript code.
Please help here.

Comment: So you want to use 2nd array as `values` of the first object?

Comment: Do you want to replace values from the first object whose `id` property matches with the `id` property of the filtered array? Or do you want to replace the entire `values` property of the first object with the filtered values array?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand question, you just need iterate by `values` array and find same `id` from second array.

```
function findAndSwitch(object1, array1): void {
  object1.values = object1.values.map(el => {
    const objToSwitch = array1.find(eleArr => eleArr.id === el.id);
    if (objToSwitch) {
      return el = objToSwitch;
    } else {
      return el;
    }
  });
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dvty4p

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your variable names are `obj1` and `arr2`, respectively. First transform `arr2` into an object `obj2`:

```
let obj2 = arr2.reduce((acc,cur) => ({...acc,[cur.id]:cur}),{});
```

Which now looks like this:

```
{
    '432112426686': {
        count: 20,
        id: '432112426686',
        name: '432112426686'
    },
    '1234456789000': {
        count: 20,
        id: '1234456789000',
        name: '1234456789000'
    }
}
```

Then transform `obj1` based on `obj2` as follows:

```
obj1.values = obj1.values.map(value => obj2[value.id] || value);
```

**Please note** that since the data in `arr2` is identical to the corresponding data in `obj1`, I have altered the values of `count` property in `arr2` in order to demonstrate that `obj1` will be updated accordingly.

**DEMO ONE**

```js
let obj1 = {
    "count": 8,
    "id": "accountId",
    "name": " Account Id",
    "values": [
        {
            "count": 2,
            "id": "1234456789000",
            "name": "1234456789000"
        },
        {
            "count": 1,
            "id": "135792468045",
            "name": "135792468045"
        },
        {
            "count": 1,
            "id": "309983110022",
            "name": "309983110022"
        },
        {
            "count": 2,
            "id": "432112426686",
            "name": "432112426686"
        },
        {
            "count": 1,
            "id": "6ee26149-a156-4665-bd26-a6e46b49a70f",
            "name": "6ee26149-a156-4665-bd26-a6e46b49a70f"
        },
        {
            "count": 1,
            "id": "927b48ce-efe4-4c20-98f0-ec6c54f59b45",
            "name": "927b48ce-efe4-4c20-98f0-ec6c54f59b45"
        }
    ]
};

let arr2 = [
    {
        "count": 20,
        "id": "432112426686",
        "name": "432112426686"
    },
    {
         "count": 20,
         "id": "1234456789000",
         "name": "1234456789000"
    }
];

let obj2 = arr2.reduce((acc,cur) => ({...acc,[cur.id]:cur}),{});
obj1.values = obj1.values.map(value => obj2[value.id] || value);

console.log( obj1 );
```

--

However, if all you want is to replace all the `obj1.values` with `arr2`, all you need is:

```
obj1.values = [...arr2];
```

And this will give rise to:

```
{
    count: 8,
    id: 'accountId',
    name: ' Account Id',
    values: [{
            count: 20,
            id: '432112426686',
            name: '432112426686'
        },
        {
            count: 20,
            id: '1234456789000',
            name: '1234456789000'
        }
    ]
}
```

**DEMO TWO**

```js
let obj1 = {
    "count": 8,
    "id": "accountId",
    "name": " Account Id",
    "values": [
        {
            "count": 2,
            "id": "1234456789000",
            "name": "1234456789000"
        },
        {
            "count": 1,
            "id": "135792468045",
            "name": "135792468045"
        },
        {
            "count": 1,
            "id": "309983110022",
            "name": "309983110022"
        },
        {
            "count": 2,
            "id": "432112426686",
            "name": "432112426686"
        },
        {
            "count": 1,
            "id": "6ee26149-a156-4665-bd26-a6e46b49a70f",
            "name": "6ee26149-a156-4665-bd26-a6e46b49a70f"
        },
        {
            "count": 1,
            "id": "927b48ce-efe4-4c20-98f0-ec6c54f59b45",
            "name": "927b48ce-efe4-4c20-98f0-ec6c54f59b45"
        }
    ]
};

let arr2 = [
    {
        "count": 20,
        "id": "432112426686",
        "name": "432112426686"
    },
    {
         "count": 20,
         "id": "1234456789000",
         "name": "1234456789000"
    }
];

obj1.values = arr2;

console.log( obj1 );
```